# Можно ли использовать carousel внутри carousel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Есть такой xhtml

```
<p:carousel var="task" value="#{customerPageBean.tasks}">
    <h:outputText value="#{task.name}"/>
    <p:carousel var="answer" value="#{task.answers}">
        <h:outputText value="#{answer.name}"/>
    </p:carousel>
</p:carousel>
```

Почему-то определяет answer как будто он типа task, ну и соответственно, далее не строит правильно вложенный карусель.

Comment: в бине все нормально. tasks - это List<SiteTask> tasks, каждый айтем листа содержит свой лист List<Answer> answers;

Comment: А как вы определили, что answer имеет тип Task?

Comment: netbeans показывает… точку ставлю после answer - нетбинс показывает свойства таска. я ему не верю, все равно внаглую подставляю свойство ансвера - вроде должно работать, но отрисовка карусели… оставляет желать лучшего…она то растягивается длиннее экрана в ширину во много раз и реакция на F5 - каждый раз новая вложенный карусель не рисуется корректно

Comment: играться пришлось с шириной… вроде все работает нормально, но нетбинс таки вводит в заблуждение… показывает свойства не того объекта. 8.1 версия нетбинса